# Is this a Suitable Approach for Handling Unseen Factor Levels?

Tags: r, categorical-data, predictive-models, random-forest, missing-data

I have the following question about using statistical models for prediction when faced with unseen factor levels. To illustrate my example, I will use the R programming language.

**Part 1: Data and Model:**

Suppose you have the following data:

```
var1 <- rnorm(100,10,1)
var2 <- rnorm(100,10,10)
var3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5) )
var4 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )
var5 <- sample( LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25) )

d1 = data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)

   var1       var2 var3 var4 var5
1 8.932176 11.1764660    B    B    C
2 9.782025  0.5252539    A    A    B
3 8.973996  5.0944256    A    B    B
4 9.271109  7.4390781    B    A    A
5 9.374961 28.4386201    A    D    A
6 8.313307  3.4805010    A    B    C
```

You are interested in predicting "var1" based on the other variables. Suppose you decide to do this using a random forest model:

```
library(randomForest)
rf =  randomForest(var1 ~ ., data=d1)
```

**Part 2: Prediction (Here is the Problem)**

Suppose you have a single new observation and you would like to predict the value of the response variable for this new observation based on the model you created above:

```
new_data = data.frame(var1 = 2, var2 = 3, var3 = "A", var4 = "GG", var5 = "L")
```

Since this observation contains unseen factor levels for var4 and var5, the random forest model will not be able to handle this.

**Part 3: Proposed Solution**

Suppose you decide to add a single row of 0's to the original data and re-train the model:

```
d2 = data.frame(var1 = 0, var2 = 0, var3 = 0, var4 = 0, var5 = 0)

old_data = rbind(d1,d2)

 rf =  randomForest(var1 ~ ., data=old_data)
```

Next, you can replace any unseen factor levels in the new data with 0:

```
library(dplyr)

new_data = new_data %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ ifelse(. %in% as.list(old_data)[[cur_column()]], ., 0)))

  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1    2    3    A    0    0
```

Now, the random forest model can handle the above data and make a new prediction:

```
pred <- predict(rf, new_data)
```

**My Question:** Is the above approach a valid approach for dealing with unseen factor variables? As far as I understand, the random forest algorithm works by taking the average (via "bagging") response variable for different combinations of the predictor variables. Thus, when unseen factor levels appear in new data - the random forest algorithm should be able to still make a "partial prediction" by querying the training data to check the average value of the response variable for the non-unseen values of the predictor variables.

Of course this is a risky approach  - but at least it allows you to make a "partial prediction" on a new observation with unseen factor levels, compared to completely discarding this observation and not being able to make any prediction whatsoever.

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, are these truly unseen levels (i.e our data contains feature x with "red","blue","green" and we need to predict "yellow") or due to sampling in our training set (i.e. we have "red" and "green" so all our instances of "blue" have landed in the test set). The former is a case of potentially missing values (during training) while the latter is easily solved by stratification. Missing values are handled in a variety of ways; we might do median/mode imputation, we might use target encoding, we might do something else; that is often implementation specific.

Comment: Breiman's RF implementation will try to impute (https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#missing1) while the R port will fail (as you have seen already :) ). Other learners (e.g. XGBoost, LightGBM) have their own methodologies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This would be an example of the first case, where "yellow" is a brand new factor level that has never been observed until the current point in time. Thanks!

Comment: OK, that is pretty implementation specific... Note that R treats categorical variables as numeric (int) so actually it could be handled in the scene of (if `var4>3` go left if not go right) but that is not currently implemented. In practice, all options suck and all options are great. The best option will be implementation specific. I would argue that most likely this should be caught *before* going to the `predict` function so we actively impute it and `predict` should indeed err. But that is to err on the side of caution, for something quick and dirty, replace with mode is likely fine too.

Comment: In general, if we need to fancy with categorical variables I would definitely consider different encoding options, target encoding being the obvious one. That would pretty much wash out the problem as unseen levels would naturally gravitate towards the mean level of the variable.